# Subversive "Compare with Revision "always fails in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, eclipse-kepler

When I try to compare a current file in Eclipse Kepler with an older revision I always get the 
message that there are no difference (which is not true) followed by the error reporting screen saying:

```
> SVN: '0x00400103: Compare with Revision' operation finished with
> error: null java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I actually switched from Subclipse to Subversive as Comparing was much more advanced there but after migrating eclipse from on computer to the other (which involed relinking my projects to there repos) I cannot use Compare anymore.

The section in the `.metadata/.logs` says:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2014-01-17 11:09:58.870
!MESSAGE SVN: '0x00400103: Compare with Revision' operation finished with error
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2014-01-17 11:09:58.870
!MESSAGE SVN: '0x00400103: Compare with Revision' operation finished with error: null
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgDiffSummarize.doDiffReposRepos(SvnNgDiffSummarize.java:229)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgDiffSummarize.doDiff(SvnNgDiffSummarize.java:86)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgDiffSummarize.run(SvnNgDiffSummarize.java:61)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgDiffSummarize.run(SvnNgDiffSummarize.java:1)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1149)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.diffSummarize(SVNClientImpl.java:1036)
    at org.polarion.team.svn.connector.svnkit.SVNKitConnector.diffStatus(SVNKitConnector.java:1599)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.extension.factory.ThreadNameModifier.diffStatus(ThreadNameModifier.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility.diffStatus(SVNUtility.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.operation.CompareResourcesInternalOperation$3.run(CompareResourcesInternalOperation.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doSubTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.protectStep(AbstractActionOperation.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.operation.CompareResourcesInternalOperation.runImpl(CompareResourcesInternalOperation.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.operation.CompareResourcesOperation$1.runImpl(CompareResourcesOperation.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.CompositeOperation.runImpl(CompositeOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.CompositeOperation.runImpl(CompositeOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.LoggedOperation.run(LoggedOperation.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTaskExternal(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.utility.DefaultCancellableOperationWrapper.run(DefaultCancellableOperationWrapper.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.utility.SVNTeamOperationWrapper.run(SVNTeamOperationWrapper.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext.run(JobRunnableContext.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext$ResourceJob.runInWorkspace(JobRunnableContext.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: The is probably a more detailed message in the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory. It may help to see that.

Comment: @greg-449 added the logs now

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be Eclipse bug [425740](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425740) which is closed as a bug in the third party SVN code: http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-427

Comment: Looks promising. Couldn't find a description on how to replace my old SVN Kit with 1.8.2 in Eclipse Kepler. Tried to simply install from the 1.8.2 update site but the SVN Kit connector used remains to be 1.8.1 after a restart.